# Android max number of persistable uri permission granted to an app is limited to 128?

Tags: android, uri, android-permissions

My application calls the Android image gallery through an intent and then the user can select multiple images. It turns out that the code listed below (already reported in other posts), works fine for me.

```
if(Utils.isKitkat())
{
    final int takeFlags = data.getFlags() & (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    for (Uri uri : images)
    {
        resolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);
    }
}
```

Anyway I noticed that the max number of persistable uri granted to my app is limited to 128. If I select more than 128 uri, I get the error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider........
```

when I try to process an image for which I wasn't able to persist the permission. Is anyone aware of the limitation? Can you figure out any solution?

Comment: I am not terribly surprised that there's a limit, though I am a bit surprised that it is that low. Are you sure that you need long-term access to the images? After all, bear in mind that the user has every ability to remove those images from their device behind your back.

Comment: @CommonsWare Any lead as to where that "128" limit could be in Gallery/Gallery2 AOSP code?

Comment: @shkschneider: I would be a bit surprised if the limit is there, though I suppose it could be. I would assume the limit is more in core Android, in whatever is tracking the persisted permissions. However, that is deeper than I normally dive into the OS, and so I have no idea exactly where to look.

Comment: @CommonsWare I need long-term access because my app shows the user-selected images at random on the desktop (My app is a wallpaper changer). Obviously this means that the uri permission shall persist across device reboots without the user re-selecting the images. When an image is deleted by user, my app removes it from the list of selected images. Do you have any idea to bypass the limitation?

Comment: "Do you have any idea to bypass the limitation?" -- other than making a local copy of the images, not off the top of my head, sorry.

Comment: Consider using [`ContentResolver.releasePersistableUriPermission()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#releasePersistableUriPermission(android.net.Uri,%20int)) to discard persistent Uri permissions when you no longer need them (e.g., if user presses Back or cancels adding a new image). Then at least you can keep the number down to those you absolutely need.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I'm running into the same issue in my app and so started looking through the Android source, and found: com.android.server.uri.UriGrantsManagerService, see [this link](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/uri/UriGrantsManagerService.java;l=108?q=lang:java%20content:%22%3D%20128%22%20AND%20content:Uri).

It defines a `private static final int MAX_PERSISTED_URI_GRANTS = 128;`

I didn't trace through exactly how this is used, other than to notice the constant is used in a private method in that class, which gets called within the takePersistableUriPermission() method. So seems like the logical "culprit".

Given that this is a private static constant, I think until they decide to change it there is no "work-around".

I entered an enhancement request to track this [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/149315521).